# Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = (total - window + 1), by = abs(step))

Tags: r

I have a dataset 1200*10, I wanto to apply a sum using this sliding window function:
slide_apply <- function (data, window, step , fun)

```
slide_apply <- function (data, window, step , fun) 
{
    fun <- match.fun(fun)
    total <- length(data)
    window <- abs(window)
    spots <- seq(from = 1, to = (total - window + 1), by = abs(step))
    result <- rep(NA, length(spots))
    for (i in 1:length(spots)) {
        result[window + i - 1] <- fun(data[spots[i]:(spots[i] + 
            window - 1)])
    }
    return(result)
}
```

but as a result I get:

```
Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = (total - window + 1), by = abs(step)) :
segno sgbagliato nell'argomento 'by'
4.
stop("wrong sign in 'by' argument")
3.
seq.default(from = 1, to = (total - window + 1), by = abs(step))
2.
seq(from = 1, to = (total - window + 1), by = abs(step))
1.
slide_apply(data = ret, window = 1200, step = 1, fun = sum)
```

I can't get the problem...

I tried to translate the input dataframe, and it works but I obtain a 12000 rows vector..so I guess something is wrong

Comment: If you do not want to troubleshoot a reinvented wheel you can try an out-of-the-box method like the `zoo::rollapply()` function to acheive the same objective